# Completely remove WiFi from Android Rom (Including Settings Layout)

Tags: android, android-layout, compilation, android-source, nexus-one

I am currently working with AOSP Gingerbread and have built a customized rom for Nexus One which excludes WiFi and Camera.
  However, WiFi can still be seen in the settings menu.
  **How do I remove it from the settings layout?**
P.S. I want the rom to be 100% free of any modules, drivers or libraries from those two.
  I had commented out `USE_CAMERA_STUB := false` from BoardConfigVendor.mk and replaced all WiFi related defines with `BOARD_HAVE_WIFI := false` in BoardConfigCommon.mk before compiling.
  **Is this modification correct or is there a better way to do it?**

Thanks.

Comment: I presume you're building a ROM for use in secure facilities. You may have a specific checklist of prohibited features, but if not, don't forget to remove bluetooth and disable the USB functionality both while booted and in your recovery rom (might be hard to do while still allowing charging - probably depends on the chipset). You may also need to permanently attach the SD card. Some facilities may also require physical removal of the wifi chipset, which may be impossible. :/

Comment: Yes I'm building it with security in mind. The only functions I was required to remove are Camera and Wifi. Thanks for sharing though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just commented out wifi and wifi settings from wireless_setting.xml and wireless_setting.java to remove them from the settings layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the appropriate drivers then the hardware just wont work.
The next thing is to do is check and decompile your android framework.apk which is situated in the folder "framework" under "system".
So in hierarchy it would be system/framework/framework-res.apk

In this framework you have to both delete the java and xml queries towards the appropriate function, so i.e. wifi.xml and the framework.jar!

Only this is the appropriate way to get rid of those functions for once and for all.